# Pegar apenas uma variável PHP de outra página com Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Para pegar o conteúdo de uma página eu utilizo o data, mas gostaria de saber como pegar apenas uma variável em outra pagina. Eu utilizo esse código:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.teste').submit( function(){
            var teste = $(this);
            var dados = teste.serialize();
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "teste.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: dados,

                success: function(data)
                {

                    teste.html(data);


                }

            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

Porém ele pega todo o conteúdo da página. Como eu faria para pegar apenas uma variável PHP, como por exemplo: "$teste". botei um exemplo abaixo para exemplificar melhor, sei que não é dessa forma.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('.teste').submit( function(){
                var teste = $(this);
                var dados = teste.serialize();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "teste.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: dados,

                    success: function(data)
                    {

                        teste.html(data.$teste);


                    }

                });

                return false;
            });
        });
```

Pagina teste.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $teste ="teste";
        $teste2 ="teste2";
        echo $teste;
        echo $teste2;
         ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual o formato do retorno?

Comment: Pode colocar na pergunta o código do arquivo `teste.php`?

Comment: Poste o codigo do teste.php

Comment: Se voce mandar na url via get nao funciona?

Comment: Se você trabalhar com retorno em `json` você consegue mapear o que quer exibir

Comment: Então só dá com JSON?

Comment: De uma forma certa sim, alem de ser a forma mais indica. Mas pode usar `web crawler` para fazer isso tambem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se é a melhor, mas uma forma da fazer isso é enviando uma variável para a página `teste.php` e nela isolar apenas o que você quer como resposta, no caso, a variável `$teste`. No retorno, eu uso o `$.trim(data)` para eliminar espaços em branco desnecessários:

**Ajax:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('.teste').submit( function(){
                var teste = $(this);
                var dados = teste.serialize();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "teste.php?variavel=ok",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: dados,

                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        teste.html($.trim(data));
                    }

                });

                return false;
            });
        });
```

Na página `teste.php`, eu pego a variável com `$_GET` (as outras informações do formulário são com `$_POST`). Tudo o que eu não quiser que retorne no Ajax, eu coloco dentro do `if`:

```
<?php
if ($variavel != "ok"){
?>
<?php } ?>
```

**Página `teste.php`:**

```
<?php
$variavel = $_GET['variavel'];

if ($variavel != "ok"){
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php } ?>
        <?php
        $teste ="teste";
        $teste2 ="teste2";
        echo $teste;
         ?>
<?php if ($variavel != "ok"){ ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Consegui fazer o que eu queria. Valeu pela resposta!

Answer (score 2):

Fazer a resposta do PHP com JSON será a forma mias fácil de tratar pelo JavaScript. Primeiro, como o arquivo PHP será requisitado através de AJAX, não é necessário ter toda essa estrutura HTML. Só faz sentido se for exibir isso de alguma forma no navegador, mas não parece ser o caso. Assim, você pode fazer no PHP:

**teste.php**

```
<?php

$teste = "valor_teste";
$teste2 = "valor_teste2";

// Indica ao navegador que a resposta será um JSON:
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode(compact("teste", "teste2"));
```

A função [`compact`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.compact.php) irá gerar um *array* na forma:

```
["teste" => "valor_teste", "teste2" => "valor_teste2"]
```

E a função [`json_encode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) converterá isso para uma *string* no formato JSON. Assim, seu JavaScript pode ficar assim:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.teste').submit( function(){

        var teste = $(this);
        var dados = teste.serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "teste.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: dados,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                teste.html(data.teste2);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Usando a propriedade `dataType` você indica que o retorno do PHP será um JSON, assim, o valor de `data` em `success` será um objeto JS criado a partir do JSON retornado pelo PHP, podendo acessar o atributo `teste2`, referente à variável `$teste2` do PHP.

Comment: Consegui fazer o que eu queria. Valeu pela resposta!